# ARM Cortex-M4: issues met when calling printf in assembly

Tags: arm, printf, thumb

I am trying to call printf in ARM M4 assembly and meet some problems. The purpose is to dump content in R1. The code is like the following

```
    .data
    .balign 4
output_string:
    dcb "content in R1 is 0x%x\n", 0
....
    .text
....
    push {r0, r1}
    mov r1, r0
    ldr r0, =output_string
    bl printf
    pop {r0, r1}
```

The problem I meet is that, when put "output_string" address into R0, the value is added with a extra 1. For example, if the symbol "output_string" have a value of 0x2000, R0 will get the value 0x2001.

I feel this has something to do with THUMB/ARM mode. But I have declare "output_string" in data section, why the assembler still translate it as an instruction address?

Or is there some more formal way to do such in-assembly function calling?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
ldr r0, =output_string
```

The `=` prefix is an assembler shorthand to make it load an arbitrary 32-bit constant. See [this ARM Information Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babdjjaj.html) page.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug that `ldr r0, output_string` produces an odd address?

Comment: Thanks for point it out, actually this is a typo when I describe the problem. I acturally use "ldr r0, =output_string" in my code, but the address loaded into r0 is "output_string + 1". I have correct it in the original post.